# ActionListener called twice, added once

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener

I created one JFrame. This JFrame contains a JLabel, which contains some JButtons. The JButtons have an ActionListener (called MainFrameListener). When the `arrowButton` Button is clicked a method is executed by the code. This method removes all ActionListeners from the old Buttons with `foodButton.removeActionListener(new MainFrameListener());`

But although I removed the Listener the Button has still two buttons.
Of course I already searched on the Internet to fix the problem and I found a line of code which shows the amount of Listeners for one Button.

```
System.out.println("Count of listeners: " + ((JButton) e.getSource()).getActionListeners().length);
```

The first time I click on the buttons Java says there are two buttons. When I click on the `arrowButton` the other menu opens and the buttons are removed. That's all like I want. When I click the `arrowBackButton` the application sends me back to the MainFrame. That's perfect. But when I click on the `arrowButton` again the Console says that I have two listeners registered for the Buttons. And the sound which comes on the click is played two times.

I don't understand that because I removed the Listeners. Is there any better method to remove Listeners?

Comment: Nice questions for a newbie, and welcome to upvote levels ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foodButton.removeActionListener(new MainFrameListener());` wont remove anything since you are removing a newly created object that has never been added to `foodButton`. Keep a reference to your listener and remove it later like this:

```
MainFrameListener listener = new MainFrameListener();
foodButton.addActionListener(listener);
//and later somewhere else
foodButton.removeActionListener(listener);
```

But my advice is to avoid adding/removing listeners in the first place.

Comment: Oh thank you. I didn't know that I need an instance for the listener. Works well now :D